# How can I use the return value from jscript in PHP?

Tags: jscript

How to access the return value from jscript in php

echo "<img src='/img/icons/print_cor.png' border='0' id='CorImg".$van."' onclick="var result = changeImage(this, $van, $numrows2, '$somret', '$taxclass');alert(result)" >";

the alert shows up a value but i want to use the result in future code in php but how ?

echo "<img src='/img/icons/print_cor.png' border='0' id='CorImg".$van."' onclick="var result = changeImage(this, $van, $numrows2, '$somret', '$taxclass');alert(result)" >";

the alert shows up a value but i want to use the result in future code in php but how ?